# What's the non-deprecated alternative to XmlDataDocument and XslTransform?

Tags: c#, xslt, .net-4.0

I am modifying some legacy code to try to eliminate warnings.  `XmlDataDocument` and `XslTransform` both generate warnings that they are obsolete.  In the case of `XslTransform` the suggested replacement is `XslCompiledTransform`, but no replacement is suggested for `XmlDataDocument`.

How can I change this code to eliminate warnings in .NET 4:

```
var xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDataDocument(myDataSet);
var xslTran = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform();
xslTran.Load(new XmlTextReader(myMemoryStream), null, null);
var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, sw, null);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
using (XmlWriter xw = doc.CreateWriter())
{
  myDataSet.WriteXml(xw);
  xw.Close();
}

XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(myMemoryStream))
{
  proc.Load(xr);
}

string result;

using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
  proc.Transform(doc.CreateNavigator(), null, sw);  // needs using System.Xml.XPath;
  result = sw.ToString();
}
```

should do I think. Of course I have only used that MemoryStream for loading the stylesheet and the StringWriter for sending the transformation result to as you code snippet used those. Usually there are other input sources or output destinations like files, or streams or Textreader.

Comment: You are right that `XDocument` does not implement `IXPathNavigable` as I thought but there is an extension method to create an `XPathNavigator` from the `XDocument`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299124.aspx. As for transforming to a `TextWriter` or `StringWriter`, that should do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163435.aspx.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin, this solution worked on multiple sections of the old code.

Comment: Martin, `XDocument` doesn't have a `CreateNavigator` method, but `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` has an overload that accepts an `XmlReader` instead, and you can use `XDocument.CreateReader` to get a suitable reader to pass to it.

Comment: John, I did already post the link to the extension method providing CreateNavigator on XDocument, I can post it again, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299124.aspx, so I am not sure why you are claiming the method does not exist, other than being misled by intellisense. But as the extension method is part of the namespace `System.Xml.XPath` intellisense only finds it with `using System.Xml.XPath;` which I also already indicated in the code sample in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

[XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) is really your main option.  I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do with the code block you've posted, but you can give something like this a shot:

```
public void DoThingsWithXml() 
{
  string strXdoc = src.GetTheXmlString(); // however it is you do it
  XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
  xdoc.LoadXml(strXdoc);
  // The other things you need to do
}
```

Comment: With respect, if you don't know what he's trying to do, then perhaps you shouldn't answer the question? I'm having to downvote you since you didn't address the issue.

Comment: @John: The issue is that he is currently being forced to use an obsolete API to work with XML, which I addressed just fine.  The code itself is quite unclear on what it's supposed to ACCOMPLISH (though this is mostly the fault of how opaque the obsolete API is), so I gave the best answer I could.  With respect, try not to be so quick to judge.

Comment: XmlDocument is now depreciated.