# ASP.Net MVC 'This method implicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework'

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, xslt, xml-parsing

In my ASP.Net MVC project the following code:

```
    <div>
    @{
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(); //new XDocument.(Model.Page as CMSPageRequest).ContentDocument;
        doc.Add(Model.Content);
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        using (var xmlReader = doc.CreateReader())
        {
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
        }
        XslTransform transform = new XslTransform();
        String _SitePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PageFilesLocation"];
        transform.Load(_SitePath + "/stylesheets/formMVC.xsl");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transform.Transform(xmlDoc, null, writer);
        var result = writer.ToString();
        @Html.Raw(result)
    }
</div>
```

Is throwing the following error:

[image]

I read the MS support article and updated my 'web.config' with the following:

```
  <runtime>
     <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
```

...but the error message is still occurring. Any suggestions on what else I can try?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try instead of getting that one to work try using one thats not depreciated. See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201627/whats-the-non-deprecated-alternative-to-xmldatadocument-and-xsltransform

Comment: @RyanSchlueter I think you are correct, unfortunately not attempts at rewriting the code have not been successful.

Comment: I use a console application and NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy at my app.config solved the issue